# MySQL to PostgreSQL: GROUP BY issues

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, mysql

So I decided to try out PostgreSQL instead of MySQL but I am having some slight conversion problems.  This was a query of mine that samples data from four tables and spit them out all in on result.

I am at a loss of how to convey this in PostgreSQL and specifically in Django but I am leaving that for another quesiton so bonus points if you can Django-fy it but no worries if you just pure SQL it.

```
SELECT links.id, links.created, links.url, links.title, user.username, category.title, SUM(votes.karma_delta) AS karma, SUM(IF(votes.user_id = 1, votes.karma_delta, 0)) AS user_vote
FROM links
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` `user` ON (`links`.`user_id`=`user`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` `category` ON (`links`.`category_id`=`category`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `votes` `votes` ON (`votes`.`link_id`=`links`.`id`)
WHERE (links.id = votes.link_id)
GROUP BY votes.link_id
ORDER BY (SUM(votes.karma_delta) - 1) / POW((TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, links.created, NOW()) + 2), 1.5) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

The IF in the select was where my first troubles began.  Seems it's an IF true/false THEN stuff ELSE other stuff END IF yet I can't get the syntax right.  I tried to use Navicat's SQL builder but it constantly wanted me to place everything I had selected into the GROUP BY and that I think it all kinds of wrong.

What I am looking for in summary is to make this MySQL query work in PostreSQL.  Thank you.

**Current Progress**

Just want to thank everybody for their help.  This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT links_link.id, links_link.created, links_link.url, links_link.title, links_category.title, SUM(links_vote.karma_delta) AS karma, SUM(CASE WHEN links_vote.user_id = 1 THEN links_vote.karma_delta ELSE 0 END) AS user_vote
FROM links_link
LEFT OUTER JOIN auth_user ON (links_link.user_id = auth_user.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN links_category ON (links_link.category_id = links_category.id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN links_vote ON (links_vote.link_id = links_link.id)
WHERE (links_link.id = links_vote.link_id)
GROUP BY links_link.id, links_link.created, links_link.url, links_link.title, links_category.title
ORDER BY links_link.created DESC
LIMIT 20
```

I had to make some table name changes and I am still working on my ORDER BY so till then we're just gonna cop out.  Thanks again!

Comment: There are numerous "Why does my query work on MySQL and not on ____" questions on SO - they *all* are related to the GROUP BY

Comment: I see well now it's time to Djagno-ify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. Drop the backticks
2. Use a CASE statement instead of IF() `CASE WHEN votes.use_id = 1 THEN votes.karma_delta ELSE 0 END`
3. Change your timestampdiff to `DATE_TRUNC('hour', now()) - DATE_TRUNC('hour', links.created)` (you will need to then count the number of hours in the resulting interval. It would be much easier to compare timestamps)
4. Fix your GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Comment: If you could elaborate on number 3 that would be a big help to me.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used mysql, but is that an attempt to order by karma and the amount of time passed? I could provide something a bit more optimized if you outline all of the goals of your query.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this link [GROUP BY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

> When GROUP BY is present, it is not
>   valid for the SELECT list expressions
>   to refer to ungrouped columns except
>   within aggregate functions, since
>   there would be more than one possible
>   value to return for an ungrouped
>   column.

You need to include all the select columns in the group by that are not part of the aggregate functions.

Comment: +1: This is the problem, sadly by design: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the `IF` with a `case`;

```
SUM(CASE WHEN votes.user_id = 1 THEN votes.karma_delta ELSE 0 END)
```

You also have to explicitly name every column or calculated column you use in the GROUP BY clause.